# SERIAL pseudo-type in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I'm using serial datatype for my project. I want to know the following details to change previously Created SEQUENCE datatype to SERAIL datatype.

1. From Which version onwards POSTGRESQL supports SERAIL DATATYPE, also If I change my id into SERAIL it wont affect my future code.
2. What is the max size of serial and its impact?
3. Can ALTER SEQUENCE  impact the Sequence numbers?
4. any drawback on serail datatype in future?
5. How to create gap-less sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers can be found in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html)

1. serial goes back to [Postgres 7.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)
2. It's a bigint, the max size is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). Also see this note in [the documenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.81.7) of `CREATE SEQUENCE`

> Sequences are based on bigint arithmetic, so the range cannot exceed the range of an eight-byte integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807).

3. Obviously. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) that command can set minvalue or restart with a new value and manipulate many other properties that affect the number generation.
4. You [should use](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) identity columns instead
5. Not possible - that's not what sequences are intended for. See e.g. [here](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/gapless-sequence/) for a possible implementation of a gapless number generator.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm so much satisfied with your answers.